# Dragging UICollectionViewCell relative to finger

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to drag a UICollectionViewCell relative to finger. This does not mean reordering the CollectionView, I just want the cell to be dragable. The current code works on a UIView, but not on a cell.

Here is what I add to the cell:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* drag;
    drag = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragging:)];

    [cell addGestureRecognizer:drag];
```

And here is the method that is invoked. The method is definitely activated, but it does not drag the cell.

```
-(void)dragging:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"dragging");
    CGPoint panCoord;
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"Received a pan gesture");
        panCoord = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];


    }
    CGPoint newCoord = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
    float dX = newCoord.x-panCoord.x;
    float dY = newCoord.y-panCoord.y;

    gesture.view.frame = CGRectMake(gesture.view.frame.origin.x+dX, gesture.view.frame.origin.y+dY, gesture.view.frame.size.width, gesture.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: What is the aim of the dragging? Are you moving it somewhere else, copying, what?

Comment: I just want to move the cell from x to newX. No inserting, no copying, just basic moving under the finger.

Comment: How would that work if you aren't reordering the collection view? And by that I take it that you don't want to modify the layout...

Comment: Yeah I don't want to modify the layout. Would I have to reorder?